# Redirect direct access to files in subfolder to script

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subfolder that holds user uploaded files. I want to redirect all direct file requests to this folder to another .php script...so i can check if the user is logged in before i send/show the file to him.
For example:

```
/mainsite/uploads/user/2324/file.pdf
```

needs to be forwarded to

```
/mainsite/uploads/permissions.php
```

But i need inside the permissions.php to be able to do:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

and see what was the initial request...in order to **readfile()** the file after all the 'checking'.

I've tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/uploads/user/?$ /uploads/permissions.php [R=301,L]
```

but this is just a simple forwarding...i got no idea what file or folder the user requested.

I know i can do this by creating an individual htaccess file inside every folder that is created under 'user/{userid}' but i wanted a simpler function. I dont want to have 10000 htaccess files, if i can do this with just one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this syntax: (i added the R=301 part, which wasn't necessary in my version, so it is not fully tested, works without the R option)

```
RewriteRule "^/uploads/user/(.+)$" "/uploads/permissions.php?file=$1" [R=301,QSA,L]
```

You can the get your `file` var in the $_GET array in `permissions.php`. However, i wouldn't recommend to use directly this value because it can be unsecure. The best way is to only allow fixed values, with a `switch` for example, having filtered the var as a string before.

Comment: Nice!! it works without the "" quotes. Yeah i know, i am checking the extension of the file requested, to see if its a document/image/etc and if not i deny the request. Also i am forcefully sending the file with 'uploads' being the root directory, so no funny business :)
Thanks